# How to read data of unknown size with socket library in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to write an http proxy in python. I'm struggling in the `.recv()` part. Where i need to recv the request sent from the browser. I also need this, for the second part, where i need to recv the response from the actual server that the browser is sending the request to.

For now i've tried this:

```
import socket

def recv_from_client(conn):
    data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            temp = conn.recv(1).decode()
        except:
            return data
        if not temp: 
            return data
        else:
            data += temp


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)

sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4269))
print("Listening for incoming connections...")
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print("Client " + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]) + " connected!")


http_request = recv_from_client(conn)

print(http_request)
```

It's a basic example, but it doesn't work correctly, when i try to send a request from the browser, it doesn't print nothing until i click the cancel button in the browser...

Apart from that, which however i will really appreciate any help to solve that, how can i make the python code read the full data (of unknown lenght)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because the size is not known to you it does not mean that the size in unknown in general. When doing HTTP you need to treat the clients request and servers response as HTTP, i.e. as head and body. Once you understand the HTTP protocol you are able to get the full response by simply following the HTTP protocol - it is all in there. And if you don't care about the actual protocol: don't try to read request and response at once but simply read a piece from one side and forward it to the other side etc.

Comment: HTTP first sends headers with two `'\n'` at the end (so it gives empty line at the end) - so you have to read till you get two `'\n'` or maybe rather two `'\r\n'`. After that it may send body but its size should be defined in headers - so you have to get size from header.

Comment: So i need to search for the Content-Lenght header, and just read until a `\r\n\r\n` is found to get all the headers, right?

Comment: yes, first you have to read until `\r\n\r\n` to get headers. If you find `Content-Lenght header` then you have to read body but you will know how many bytes it should have.